# "Post has been deleted" banner is not Responsive

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, design

I just watched a post getting deleted right in front of my face and found out the banner is not responsive.
[image]

Also on mobile doesn't look too good:
[image]
*click to enlarge*
*iPhone 6/7/8 Plus according to Chrome*

Details:
Google Chrome 67.0.3396.87
MacOS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: It is fine in [MSE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGmwl.png)

Comment: In my case the deleted post was an answer. Not sure if would be the same as questions

Comment: Fine with [answer too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGqZU.png) in MSE

Comment: Excuse me sir but your freehand circles are in [perpendicular] invisible ink

Comment: I can only draw freehanded with invisible ink. New technology. Sorry @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have updated the styles on this component so that they work more responsively.